# When onTrimMemory is called in a service

Tags: android, service, android-service

I have a *`START_STICKY`* service and each time when I pause the activity (when I minimize) service is calling `onTrimMemory`. I wanted to know, in what and all scenarios this callback will be called. Its only during App minimize(the activity onPause)?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html

Answer (score 0):

The callback can be called in app_visible and app_hiding conditions, but the important thing is that when the `onTrimMemory(int i )` is called, you must be ready to react to the situation.

The different meanings and occurrences of the method and its argument `i` can be found in the [documentation.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ComponentCallbacks2.html)

Comment: _`TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN `_ flag can be used for app_hiding conditions, but what about app_visible condition? which callback will be triggered.